# Communicate with an AngularJS Directive that manipulates DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am currently developing a simple one-page app where you click some `<li>` and you are able to send some data with `ngClick`. This `<li>`s have a parent `<div>` where I apply CSS styles with `angular.element` and all that stuff...

The problem is when I click this `ngClick` I do some `$http` calls and get a JSON to fill an internal controller variable. So, when the user clicks other menu that has nothing in common (in terms of controllers and directives) I fill other list and when the user clicks this list, I have to style the `<li>`s I mentioned before, that is a directive.

So, I don't know how to tell the `link` reference on the `directive`, that it must style with some properties that I don't know how to pass too, maybe a service to read ? I thought of using a service to store the info to pass from the controller to the directive, but I am new to Angular and am not sure what to do. I searched a lot but didn't find exactly what I am looking for. I thought of using `$watch` but my variables to watch that are on a controller, so I must go to parent scope like 2 times back to reach it.

Thanks a lot !

Comment: You can use ng-style or ng-class according to whatever condition is .

Comment: I can't use it, because I recibe from the JSON some images that I will used as `background-image` that will be loaded from a Database. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl as ctrl" ng-style="ctrl.style">
   <my-dir on-fetch="ctrl.style = $style"></my-dir>
</div>

module.directive('myDir', function(){
    return {
       restrict: 'E',
       template: '<li ng-click="$ctrl.fetch()"></li>',
       controller: function(){
           var $ctrl = this;
           this.fetch = function(){
               api.fetch().then(function(stylesFromResponse){
                   $ctrl.onFetch({$style: stylesFromResponse});
               });
           };
       },
       bindToController: true,
       controllerAs: '$ctrl',
       scope: {
          onFetch: '&'
       }
    };
});
```

Comment: I nearly dont understand anything you wrote... Could you explain in your answer so I can adapt it, thanks !

Comment: As I understand, you have directive, which should fetch data onClick, and communicate with parent controller, when data is fetched. In my example that fetching li is myDir, it handle onClick internally and call controller method or outer code, when fetching is ready.

Comment: I edit example, to show, how to provide value to outer code